# SQL Server INSERT INTO special

Tags: sql-server, insert-into

I have a problem for which I would really appreciate your help.

I have 4 tables:

- **PatientList** with columns HISID varchar (64), LastName varchar (64), FirstName varchar (64), MiddleName varchar (64) and LastVisit datetime
- **ABP** with columns HISID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName and ScanDateTime
- **Holter** with columns HISID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName and ScanDateTime
- **Resting** with columns HISID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName and ScanDateTime

I need to fill the `PatientList` table with DISTINCTs `HISID` from tables `ABP`, `Holter` and `Resting`, also with `LastName`, `FirstName` and `MiddleName` and with the more recent `ScanDateandTime` into `LastVisit` column.

For instance:

**ABP** table has

```
ID001, Doe, John, William, 2018-06-01 15:00
ID001, Doe, John, William, 2018-06-05 12:00
ID002, Parson, Rob, Michael, 2018-05-03 11:35
ID002, Parson, Rob, Michael, 2018-04-20 19:30
```

**Resting** table has

```
ID001, Doe, John, William, 2018-04-01 11:11
ID003, Andersen, Pamela, Erwin, 2018-06-20 20:00
```

**Holter** table has

```
ID002, Parson, Rob, Michael, 2018-05-30 11:00
ID001, Doe, John, William, 2018-06-28 12:45
ID003, Andersen, Pamela, Erwin, 2017-12-15 08:00
```

The resulting `PatientList` table should be sorted by `LastVisit DESC`:

```
ID001, Doe, John, William, 2018-06-28 12:45
ID003, Andersen, Pamela, Erwin, 2018-06-20 20:00
ID002, Parson, Rob, Michael, 2018-05-30 11:00
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just to clarify: Is `PatientList` an actual table whereinto you're inserting the values from the `APB`, `Resting`, and `Holter` tables? Or is it simply a VIEW you wish to create? Regarding your last comment ("The resulting `PatientList` table should be sorted by `LastVisit DESC`"): You can't really define the sort order of a table (or view). If you're selecting from `PatientList`, you'll have to specify the SORT order when you run the query (e.g. `select * from PatientList order by LastVisit DESC`).

Comment: Thank you Zack and David. BoCoKeith below answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH
    a AS (
        SELECT ID, Last, First, Middle, Date FROM Holter
        UNION
        SELECT ID, Last, First, Middle, Date FROM ABP
        UNION
        SELECT ID, Last, First, Middle, Date FROM Resting
    ) ,
    b AS (
        SELECT ID, Last, First, Middle, Date,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RowNumber
        FROM   a
    )
INSERT  Patient
SELECT  ID, Last, First, Middle, Date
FROM    b
WHERE   RowNumber = 1;
```

Comment: Hello BoCoKeith. Thanks for your prompt reply. Unfortunately it gives me an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'". Do you know what it might be?

Comment: I found out that after ROW_NUMBER it should be ().

Comment: Thank you BoCoKeith. It works as desired. Many thanks.

Comment: (Jose, would you mind upvoting and accepting the answer if it's good enough for you?  Try to get some creds on SO.  Thanks!  Also, thanks for pointing out the typo -- I've corrected it.)